A NAND gate with propagation delay in VHDL
I want to design a NAND gate (\$t_{PLH}\$ = \$t_{PHL}\$ = 10ns) with VHDL.
\$t_{PLH}\$ = Propagation delay low to high
\$t_{PHL}\$ = Propagation delay high to low
This is first code.
library IEEE;               
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity nand_gate is
    Port ( A : in STD_LOGIC;
           B : in STD_LOGIC;
           X : out STD_LOGIC);
end nand_gate;

architecture Behavioral of nand_gate is

begin

    X <= A nand B after 10 ns;

end Behavioral;

This is second one:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity NAND_GATE is
    port (
        A, B : in  STD_LOGIC;
        Y    : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end NAND_GATE;

architecture Behavioral of NAND_GATE is
    
begin
    process(A, B)
    begin

       Y <= A nand B after 10 ns;
    end process;
end Behavioral;

What is the difference between these codes?
What changes if I use the term "process" for short?
I write a test bench and I simulate this code. Both are exactly the same. Then why do we use the term "process"?

your design adds a delay at every input change: At 40 A=B=1 which leads to X=0 at 50; B=0 at 50 leads to X=1 at 60.

@Matthias Schweikart When I changed the delay time, I saw that my design adds a delay on each input change.
However, I would expect it not to add a delay on each input change without the "process" statement. Is there any difference between the code above and another code that includes the "process"  statement?

A concurrent assignment not included in a process behaves like an assignment included in a process, which is sensitive to the signals read in the assignment. So there is no difference between the code above and another code using a process.

A concurrent assignment not included in a process behaves like an assignment included in a process, which is sensitive to the signals read in the assignment. So there is no difference between the code above and another code using a process.
